# How can I know if some condition of tuple is in the set or not?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I've just started to use Python from scratch.

My problem is:

Let's say there exist a list called 'list' having some tuples inside as below.

```
list = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
```

I want to know if there's some tuples inside that the second element is 2.

What I tried was:

```
(_,2) in list
```

but it returns False value, even though there's (1,2) inside.

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance :)

```
>> list = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

>> (_,2) in list
```

Comment: Note that your „set“ is actually a list. Either, what you describe is pattern matching, for which Python has no inbuilt support. Depending on the complexity of your pattern, you can do an explicit search or should use a pattern matching library such as pampy.

Comment: My mistake, thanks :) I fixed!

Comment: Please do not name your data after types! It shadows the reference to the actual type,making it inaccessible.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not in my actual code, that was just to clarify. Thanks for information:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `set = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]` is of type list.

you want to find out that in each tuple is there 2 in 2nd value of it. then all you need to do:

```
1. iterate over each tuple of set
2. on each tuple check that 2nd element is 2 or not
```

here is code

```
# your code goes here
set = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
for tple in set:
     first_element, second_element = tple
     if second_element==2:
        print('YES')
```

Comment: `for first_element, second_element in tple` won't work because `tple` is a tuple of integers, and you'd need it to be a tuple of tuples: `((1,2), (3,4))` for this to work

Comment: @prashantrana Thanks :) Then how can I extract that tuple of condition? tuple = (ele if ele[1] == 2 else _ for ele in list) doesn't work

Comment: @VivaStudio `tuples =  [tpl for tpl in set if tpl[1]==2] `

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the *list* (not set) and check if the second element of the current tuple is equal to 2:

```
any(second == 2 for first, second in [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)])
```